# Will my Australian residency visa appear in my renewed UK passport?

Tags: visas, uk, australia, passport-renewals

I am currently in the process of renewing my British passport while living in Australia. Once it's been renewed, will it have a copy of my permanent residency visa? Or does it just stay in my expired one and I get that back?

Comment: Did you ask the Consulate? That should be the first step. Generally, when an old passport has a valid visa, the passport is cancelled and returned. HMPO (or any other passport issuing authority) is certainly not going to make copies of visas issued by other countries...

Comment: The UK passport office won't transfer your visas. I can't speak for Australia, but NZ Permanent Resident visas are  only valid in a valid passport.  Every time I've renewed a UK passport here I have had to send the passport to Immigration NZ with the required application form and fee to have the visa transferred.

Answer (score 3):

**No.** Australian visas are now [completely electronic](https://www.border.gov.au/aboutyourvisa) and linked to your passport number.  Visa labels are obsolete and no longer necessary.

When you get your new passport, you will need to advise the Department of [your new passport details](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/how-can-i-update-my-address-or-passport-details) so that the visa can be transferred across electronically.  You will not get a new label.

Answer (score 2):

The Passport Office will not do anything to the visa in the old passport. All they will do is slice the corner off the photo page and cover to indicate that the passport is cancelled. You will get this passport back, with the visa intact (no corner cut off). In most circumstances, said visa is valid for travel in conjunction with the new passport, but that's another question.

Comment: Source: Personal experience. The US visa in my old British passport was left untouched upon renewal

Comment: NZ PR visas are only valid in a valid passport. The OP should check whether their visa will remain valid in a cancelled passport. Australian PR visas are only valid for five years anyway. so they will have to renew it at some point before the passport needs to be renewed again.